# Add item to the default TextBox context menu

Tags: c#, winforms

is there any way to add an extra item to the default WinForms TextBox context menu without creating my own?

Answer (score 2):

Subclass TextBox (derive from it) or native handle (with NativeWindow), and then override window procedure as follows:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
  if (m.Msg == <your menu id>) { ... return; }
  ...

  if (m.Msg == 0x0093 /*WM_UAHINITMENU*/ || m.Msg == 0x0117 /*WM_INITMENUPOPUP*/ || m.Msg == 0x0116 /*WM_INITMENU*/)
  {
    IntPtr shortcut = m.Msg == 0x0093 ? Marshal.ReadIntPtr(m.LParam) : m.WParam;
    // add <your menu id> to shortcut
    ...
  }
  ...
  base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should override WndProc and capture the messages that the textbox receive.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but complicated. I suggest you implement your own menu using "modern" ContextMenuStrip class instead of standard ContextMenu.