# How can I add my own item to the default context menu of a textbox (cut, copy, paste, <my item>).

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm surprised how hard it is to find a solution to this question.  I can't seem to find anyone else asking it.

I have some basic textbox controls on my form.  In addition to the standard cut/copy/paste options when you right click in the box, I want to add my own additional item.

Any idea how I can achieve this?  I don't even know where to start.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[It's been suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346473/add-item-to-the-default-textbox-context-menu) to implement your own menu; you can [provide the default actions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/csharpgeneral/thread/30a82a3a-a085-49f4-a5aa-f2eebeeba1e5) and add your own as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking out the control called ContextMenuControl. This control allows you to create a menu and assign it to the controls that you would like to have this menu pop up with. then when a user right-clicks on the textbox, your menu will pop up.

Have a look at this:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984254(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984254%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)