# How to detect click from default context menu (ComboBox)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-3.5

I have a ComboBox in a Winforms C# project. When the user right clicks the ComboBox to bring up a context menu, then selects an item (left click) from the default ContextMenuStrip, I want to be able to capture that event. Which event should I handle?

Is it possible to do this without making my own custom ContextMenuStrip? If I have to make my own, is there a good way to use the Windows default ContextMenuStrip as a starting point?

Edit:
This question is similar:
[Add item to the default TextBox context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1346473/334855)

But it is talking about adding items to the default menu. I am asking about capturing events selecting an item from the default context menu. If I need to make a custom ContextMenuStrip to do this, that is fine, please answer that way.

Comment: just register the click event on the contextmenu

Comment: and how do you do that for the default ContextMenuStrip?

Comment: contextmenustrip seems to have a `onclick` event - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.aspx - you could override this perhaps?

Comment: I appreciate your help but you both seem to be not quite addressing the fact that I am inquring about the default ContextMenuStrip

Comment: hmm sorry about that I thought you were asking about a custom ContextMenu

Comment: Updated my answer, please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I had initially misunderstood the question, but have now modified my answer to show you how to detect a click from the context menu

While searching for a solution, I came across many articles that pointed to WinProc. Going down that avenue, I came across the following

- [Menu Reference in Windows Application UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468864%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Since you are interested in the click command, I went into Menu Notifications and then checked out the [WM_MENUCOMMAND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647603%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.

You will then have to create a user control and change it to inherit from textbox and add the following overrides

```
public partial class TextBoxUsingDefaultContextMenu : TextBox
{
    public TextBoxUsingDefaultContextMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const int WM_CONTEXTMENU = 0x007B;
        const int WM_MENUCOMMAND = 0x0126;
        const int WM_COMMAND = 0x0111;

        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_CONTEXTMENU:
                MessageBox.Show("Opening Context Menu");
                break;

            case WM_MENUCOMMAND:
                MessageBox.Show("WM Menu Command Event fired");
                break;

            case WM_COMMAND:
                MessageBox.Show("WM Command Event fired");
                break;

        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    protected override void DefWndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.DefWndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

W.r.t the code above, I can detect the "Context Menu Opening" event but not yet the clicked event. Any help here will be appreciated from others and even this topic is new to me.

Comment: I agree, I would follow this method for developing a custom ContextMenuStrip. However, I see nothing about detecting events from the default Windows ContextMenuStrip

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. I'll check this solution out.

Comment: Hello @ford, while i could detect the WM_CONTEXTMENU event. I could not detect WM_COMMAND or WM_MENUCOMMAND. If you could get it to work, could you please inform me. Would appreciate it!

Comment: Romulus, thanks for your help. Looks like my answer for now is "it's far easier to make your own custom context menu".

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of `ContextMenuStrip` events that might help you.
The `MouseClick` event gives you a `MouseEventArgs` parameter that includes which mouse button was clicked.
The `ItemClicked` event gives you a `ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs` parameter that includes the menu item that was clicked.
`MouseClick` fires before `ItemClicked` and you'll need to use variables defined at the form class level to communicate between the two.